# Pattern Matching Email Address with <...>

Tags: java, regex, email

how is a pattern defined to check whether it's a valid Email-address with optional arrows like `<example.com>` which shouldn't be necessary. And if the Email-address begins with `<` but doesn't end with the enclosing `>` it should be ignored as well as `< .... >>` etc..

Can anybody help me?

The pattern for an Email-address is

```
^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$;
```

Comment: Why don't you use mailapi instead? It has InternetAddress which can validate that for you in a reliable, RFC-compliant manner

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex :

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&’*+/=?`{|}~^-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9_!#$%&’*+/=?`{|}~^-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$
```

Comment: [You thought you only had two problems... Here is a regexplained](http://tinyurl.com/za9pdbn)